# Problem with photo attachments from salesforce in public site

Tags: community

So, i have public site. This is site has aura component. This is aura component must show product2 photo attachment. 
If i use

> img src="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + v.photoAttachmentId}"

or

> img src="{!'registration/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + v.photoAttachmentId}"

Site not display photo attachment. But if I use full path

> img src="{!'https://brave-panda-az6uer-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + v.photoAttachmentId}"

Site display attachments if I Avtorizirovannyj, else - not;
I don't know what do... Help me pleas. Attachments I added by salesforce classic

Comment: Have you checked if the photo is also displayed when your user is not logged in? (such as in an incognito window?) If not, it would be a permissions topic.

Notice as well that domain would be different. one is documentforce.com and the other one would be .force.com.

Comment: @SergioAlcocer. yes, if you open site in incognito window you will see this problem. What permissions should be issued?